# GROUP BY on column, aggregation and transform results

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, aggregation

i have the following table:

```
date       | data_type | data_value
01-01-2023 |  max      |    4
02-01-2023 |  min      |    7
03-01-2023 |  avg      |    54
04-01-2023 |  max      |    8
05-01-2023 |  min      |    98
06-01-2023 |  avg      |    23
01-02-2023 |  max      |    65
02-02-2023 |  min      |    2
03-02-2023 |  avg      |    45
04-02-2023 |  max      |    22
05-02-2023 |  min      |    56
06-02-2023 |  avg      |    65
01-03-2023 |  max      |    7
02-03-2023 |  min      |    5
03-03-2023 |  avg      |    23
04-03-2023 |  max      |    65
05-03-2023 |  min      |    51
06-03-2023 |  avg      |    33
```

from the following table I would need to group by current month and from it take the max of its values ​​with data_type 'max', the lesser of those of type 'min' and finally the average of the types 'avg', as follows:

```
mounth | max | min |  avg
1      |  8  |  7  |  38,5
2      |  65 |  2  |  55
3      |  65 |  5  |  28
```

---

I therefore wanted to ask you which is the most performing SQL query in order to resolve the request.

Thank you all.

Comment: What SQL statement did you write to solve this yourself, and where did it fail ?

Comment: What should be done when there is more than 1 year (In 12 month time there will be a `01-01-2024` ....)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation as the following:

```
select year(date_) as 'yaer',
       month(date_) as 'month',
       min(case when data_type = 'min' then data_value end) as 'min',
       max(case when data_type = 'max' then data_value end) as 'max',
       avg(case when data_type = 'avg' then data_value end) as 'avg'
from tbl
group by year(date_), month(date_)
```

Or, if you want to aggregate for a specific year:

```
select month(date_) as 'month',
       min(case when data_type = 'min' then data_value end) as 'min',
       max(case when data_type = 'max' then data_value end) as 'max',
       avg(case when data_type = 'avg' then data_value end) as 'avg'
from tbl
where year(date_) = 2023
group by month(date_)
```

[See demo.](https://dbfiddle.uk/Vmr6FAvn)